I don't see the installation ID when using Firebase in-app messenging
I am trying to use the firebase in-app messaging package in my flutter app.
According to firebase doc (https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/get-started?hl=fr&platform=flutter) i should get the installationID in the logs. I am running app on either debug or release mode but did'nt seem to get the log message from FIAM (Android):
I/FIAM.Headless: Starting InAppMessaging runtime with Installation ID YOUR_INSTALLATION_ID
Method fiam.app.options does returns value according to the methods.
and sometime i get these logs from debugger :
I/FIAM.Display(15898): Unbinding from activity: MainActivity
I/FIAM.Headless(15898): Removing display event component

i have enabled the Firebase In-App Messaging API in Google cloud.
Although i'm not sure if needed, I have added the dependencies in app/build.gradle :
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging:21.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:21.0.0'

I am creating an instance of firebaseInAppMessaging in my main() file :
import 'package:firebase_in_app_messaging/firebase_in_app_messaging.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  firebaseApp = await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
FirebaseInAppMessaging fiam = FirebaseInAppMessaging.instance;
//...
}


This problem happens because the Flutter DevTool Debugger starts to show log output just after the FIAM (Firebase In-App Messaging) initialized, thus, the installation ID couldn't be shown.
You can find the installation ID by manually viewing the APK log using ADB.
First, run:
adb devices
to get the list of devices, and copy your device ID.
Then, run:
adb -s "device_id" logcat FIAM.Headless:I *:S
You will find the installation ID in the log output which you can use to perform in-app messaging tests on your development device.

That is indeed the reason why! thanks a lot !
